# How can I replace this madness?

Tags: regular-expression

How can I replace an instance of

```
id="ogwb"
```

with

```
id="ogwb" name="ogwb" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['ogwb']); ?>"
```

using `sed` or alternative?

Comment: I suspect you are working at the wrong layer of abstraction.

Comment: You mean I have the wrong idea? Why don't you just say that?

Comment: What is the difficulty you are having?  The quoting, or what?  (I suspect you have architectural issues you should resolve and/or redesign, but if you *must* do this text processing at this architectural level, you can do it easily with `sed`.  Have you tried?)

Comment: Which characters need to be escaped? I tried `sed 's/id="ogwb"/id="ogwb" name="ogwb" value="<\?php echo htmlspecialchars\(\$_POST\[\'ogwb\'\]\); \?>"/g'` to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

A proper command:

```
sed -E 's/^id="([^"]+)"$/& name="\1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['"'\1'"']); ?>"/'
```

Note that this switches from double quotes to single quotes when it is necessary to embed single quotes.  You can't embed single quotes inside of single quotes in Bash.  Period.

But this doesn't matter, because quotes aren't string *terminators* in Bash, they're just delimiters between different styles of quoting.  So:

```
some-command 'This is in a single quoted string'"'"'This is another quoted string, but is part of the same argument to some-command'
                                                ^^^
                             This single quote is inside of double quotes.
```

If you don't want to worry about how shell quoting interacts with `sed`, stick your `sed` command in a file and call it with `sed -f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'id="ogwb"' | sed 's,id=\(.*\),id=\1 name=\1 value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[\1]); ?>",'
```